# Stash - conditional doesn't work

Tags: stash

Here is my code

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="xxxxx" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        category="{embed:category_id}" 
        channel="xxxxx" 
        disable="categories|category_fields|custom_fields|member_data|pagination" 
        dynamic="no"
    }
            {if '{exp:plugin:that_returns_some_boolean}' == 'true'}
                {stash:item}    
                    {exp:plugin:that_returns_some_value}
                {/stash:item}
            {/if}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="xxxxx"}
    {if count == 1}
        <li>
        {exp:plugin:that_returns_some_string}:&nbsp;
    {/if}

    {if item}
        {item}
        {if count != total_results}
            ,
        {/if}
    {/if}

    {if count == total_results}
        </li>
    {/if}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

The basic gist of this code block is to simply put some values in the Stash list based on some conditional.

My problem is that the conditional that wraps `{stash:item}` doesn't seem to be respected. `{stash:item}` is always appended to the list. Because of that, I see all the items outputted by `{exp:stash:get_list}` as if the conditional doesn't exist.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding

```
 {exp:stash:set_list name="xxxxx" parse_conditionals = "yes" parse_tags="yes"}
```

To your initial set_list tag. You may also be better off using switchee instead of if ... Try adding the above first.

IF switchee isnt working then maybe try [ifelse](https://github.com/croxton/ifElse) (also by Croxton). The issue I believe is parse order and in particular the parsing of the plugin inside the if statement, hopefully ifelse will correct the parse order issue.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="xxxxx" parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries
        category="{embed:category_id}" 
        channel="xxxxx" 
        disable="categories|category_fields|custom_fields|member_data|pagination" 
        dynamic="no"
    }
        {exp:ifelse parse="inward"} //ifelse module
            {if '{exp:plugin:that_returns_some_boolean}' == 'true'}
                {stash:item}    
                    {exp:plugin:that_returns_some_value}
                {/stash:item}
            {/if}
         {/exp:ifelse}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Comment: `parse_conditionals="yes"` made it so that nothing is outputted. Will try switchee.

Comment: Btw, which conditional?

Comment: Seems to me that switchee did not solve anything.

Comment: Updated my reply :)

Comment: It was a combination of using switchee AND setting `trim="yes" to the `set_list` parameter that solved the problem. I am not sure which one I should mark as the answer though.

Comment: avinsim, would you mind updating your OP with your working code, I have a similar thing I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the conditional on the inside of the `{stash:item}` pair. In addition, you may need to add `trim="yes"` to the `set_list` parameters to ensure that the variable is not set to some whitespace when the condition doesn't apply. You'll also need `parse_conditionals="yes"` as mentioned already.

If that doesn't help, double check exactly what your plugin is returning (is it the word 'true', or is it a boolean TRUE, or 1 or 0 or yes/no etc)

Comment: It was a combination of using switchee AND setting `trim="yes" to the `set_list` parameter that solved the problem. I am not sure which one I should mark as the answer though.

Comment: Mark mine for sure, James has too many points anyway ;)